# How to check current time and DB time is equal in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement, timezone

I am trying to compare 2 times in `PHP`. I fetched and stored the time in notepad from `Mysql`, like

- 21:30
- 22:00
- 22:30

Then I reading time from the `file` and storing it in an `array`.Below is my code

```
$myfile = file('Scheduled_data.txt');
$time_array = array();

// store into array 
foreach ($myfile as $line) {
    $line_array = explode("\t", $line);
    $time_array[] =  $line_array[0];
}

//looping array 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($time_array); $i++) {
    $timezone = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata') );
    $current_time=$timezone->format('H:i');
    echo  $time_array[$i]; //ex: first data 21:30
    echo "\t";
    echo $current_time; // 21:30
    if($time_array == $current_time)
    { 
      echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
    }
}
```

I am not able to move inside in `If condition`. but I can see the same time while printing the time.

Updated: Sorry I did this only but still not going inside `If` condition

```
if($time_array[$i] == $current_time)
        { 
          echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
        }
```

**Note** both type is string only and tried to compare using `===` still no use.

Comment: You are putting `$time_array` in `if` statement which is an array. You need to put `$time_array[$i]`

Comment: sorry i tried this only but not going inside if cond @ManishPareek

Comment: `var_dump` both `$time_array[$i]` and `$current_time` and check the result

Comment: '13:33
' (length=6)
 '13:40' (length=5)  i got this  first 13:33 is from db

Comment: @AnuPriya you got an space in first time. just trim and compare

Comment: so your first string has a space included due to which your comparison failed. You should trim the unwanted space. Do this: `if(trim($time_array[$i]) === $current_time)`

Comment: i trim the string now eventhough its not same it's going inside if 
DB : '13:45' (length=5)  Currenttime: '13:46' (length=5)
if (var_dump(trim ($time_array[$i])  == var_dump(trim ($current_time)) ) - itried @ManishPareek

Comment: @AnuPriya As you see the `13:45` from DB is not equal to `13:46`. My answer's solution is actually your answer. Please check it and if it is true, mark it as true!

Answer (score 0):

However the thing you did is not a best practice, but you are making a mistake on comparing an array with a string on:

```
if($time_array == $current_time)
{ 
  echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
}
```

#### Solution

you need to check the `$i`th index of `$time_array` with the `$current_time` like this:

```
if(strtotime($time_array[$i]) == strtotime($current_time))
{ 
  echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
}
```

### So:

It is better to use [strtotime() php function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to compare:

```
$myfile = file('Scheduled_data.txt');
$time_array = array();

// store into array
foreach ($myfile as $line) {
    $line_array = explode("\t", $line);
    $time_array[] =  $line_array[0];
}

//looping array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($time_array); $i++) {
    $timezone = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata') );
    $current_time=$timezone->format('H:i');
    echo  $time_array[$i]; //ex: first data 21:30
    echo "\n\r";
    echo $current_time; // 21:30
    if(strtotime($time_array[$i]) == strtotime($current_time)){ 
        echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
    }
}
```

#### Notice

by the way it is better to compare two variable with `===` operator as it will check the type of them

Comment: sorry i tried this only but not going inside if cond , and tried of comparing using ===still no use @Akinak

Answer (score -1):

For comparison, you need to convert both times in `milliseconds` using `PHP strtotime`.

Just replace your `if` condition

```
if(strtotime($time_array[$i]) == strtotime($current_time))
{ 
    echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
}
```

Rather than using `DateTime class` you can try the below code using the `PHP DATE()` function it's save your number of lines.

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($time_array); $i++)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    if(strtotime($time_array[$i]) == strtotime(date('H:i')))
    { 
      echo "yes"; // not moving inside if cond
    }
}
```

For more refrence : [PHP strtotime() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)